# Python Base64 encoding result different from online tool

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, base64

I am trying to encode a pdf document. The encoded document is sent over an API to generate the response.I used 2 ways of encoding the document : First one was to use the online tool https://www.base64encode.org/ and the second one was by using the python library base64. But I am getting two different results for the same document and the one generated by the online tool is the correct one since I am get a success response from the API. 
Result from online tool:

> 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

Python code :

```
import base64

from base64 import b64encode

file="file.pdf"
def bas64(file):
    path="Path to parent folder\\"
    with open(path+file) as f:
        encoded = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    return encoded

output=bas64(file1)
```

Result :

> 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

Any thoughts on what is causing the issue ?

Comment: Please take a couple of minutes to go over the icons above the post when you're in edit mode: use "code" for code, and "quotes" when you're quoting etc.

Comment: Do you know what `f.read()` returns ?

Comment: @ Alfasin: Sorry about that. I tried doing f.read and it returns  a string: 
                                                                                                         
 '%PDF-1.4\n%\xaa\xab\xac\xad\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Creator (Apache FOP Version 1.1)\n/Producer (Apache FOP Version 1.1)\n/CreationDate (D:20170907145451Z)\n>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<<\n  /N 3\n  /Length 11 0 R\n  /Filter /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nx\x9c\x9d\x96wXS\xe7\x1e\xc7\xdfsN\xf6`$!l\x08{\x86\xa5@\x00\x91\x11\xa6\x80\x0c\xd9\xa2\x10\x92\x00\x01\x12 $\x0c\xf7@T\xb0\xa2\xa8\xc8R\x04)\'

Comment: @ Alfasin :I also see an error in my internal console when I try to view the content of f.read() : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 10: invalid start byte

Comment: Perhaps need to open the file in binary mode?

Comment: base64 encoding is for bytes, so you need to open the file using `rb` mode.

Comment: @kindall : I tried doing that but I get the same result.

Comment: Have you tried decoding each result to see what it encodes?

Comment: As Kindall suggested , I have to open the file in  rb mode. A point to be noted here is that the strings generated by the online tool and python were completely different.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52255674/4288043)