# Base64 encoding issue in Python

Tags: python, encoding, base64, decoding

I need to save a params file in python and this params file contains some parameters that I won't leave on plain text, so I codify the entire file to base64 (I know that this isn't the most secure encoding of the world but it works for the kind of data that I need to use).

With the encoding, everything works well. I encode the content of my file (a simply txt with a proper extension) and save the file. The problem comes with the decode. I print the text coded before save the file and the text coded from the file saved and there are exactly the same, but for a reason I don't know, the decode of the text of the file saved returns me this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1: invalid start byte` and the decode of the text before save the file works well.

Any idea to resolve this issue?

This is my code, I have tried converting all to bytes, to string, and everything...

```
params = open('params.bpr','r').read()


paramsencoded = base64.b64encode(bytes(params,'utf-8'))

print(paramsencoded)

paramsdecoded = str(base64.b64decode(str(paramsencoded,'utf-8')),'utf-8')

newparams = open('paramsencoded.bpr','w+',encoding='utf-8')
newparams.write(str(paramsencoded))
newparams.close()

params2 = open('paramsencoded.bpr',encoding='utf-8').read()
print(params2)

paramsdecoded = str(base64.b64decode(str(paramsencoded,'utf-8')),'utf-8')

paramsdecoded = base64.b64decode(str(params2))

print(str(paramsdecoded,'utf-8'))
```

Comment: You don't need to decode the `paramsencoded` bytes value to a string each time you want to decode the Base64 data. `b64decode()` accepts bytes too.

Comment: And instead of reading as text (with `'r'`) then encoding to bytes, why not read the file as binary (use `'rb'` as the mode)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you open the file for `paramsencoded.bpr` as `'w+'`? You only need to write, not also read, so `+` can be dropped. The same remark there: open in binary mode and write the `bytes` value directly without first decoding to `str`.

Comment: Last but not least, can you give us a sample `params` value that reproduces the problem?

Comment: There is no need to use `str(params2)` when you just read text from the `open('paramsencoded.bpr',encoding='utf-8').read()` call. Where exactly is the `UnicodeDecodeError` thrown, on the last line?

Answer (score 4):

Your error lies in your handling of the `bytes` object returned by `base64.b64encode()`, you called `str()` on the object:

```
newparams.write(str(paramsencoded))
```

That *doesn't decode* the `bytes` object:

```
>>> bytesvalue = b'abc='
>>> str(bytesvalue)
"b'abc='"
```

Note the `b'...'` notation. You produced the *representation* of the bytes object, which is a string containing Python syntax that can reproduce the value for debugging purposes (you can copy that string value and paste it into Python to re-create the same `bytes` value).

This may not be that easy to notice at first, as `base64.b64encode()` otherwise only produces output with printable ASCII bytes.

But your decoding problem originates from there, because when decoding the value read back from the file includes the `b'` characters at the start. Those first two characters are interpreted as Base64 data *too*; the `b` is a valid Base64 character, and the `'` is ignored by the parser:

```
>>> bytesvalue = b'hello world'
>>> base64.b64encode(bytesvalue)
b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
>>> str(base64.b64encode(bytesvalue))
"b'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='"
>>> base64.b64decode(str(base64.b64encode(bytesvalue)))  # with str()
b'm\xa1\x95\xb1\xb1\xbc\x81\xdd\xbd\xc9\xb1\x90'
>>> base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode(bytesvalue))       # without str()
b'hello world'
```

Note how the output is **completely different**, because the Base64 decoding is now starting from the wrong place, as `b` is the first 6 bits of the first byte (making the first decoded byte a 6C, 6D, 6E or 6F bytes, so `m`,`n`, `o` or `p` ASCII).

You could properly decode the value (using `paramsencoded.decode('ascii')` or `str(paramsencoded, 'ascii')`) but you should't treat any of this data as text.

Instead, open your files in *binary mode*. Reading and writing then operates with `bytes` objects, and the `base64.b64encode()` and `base64.b64decode()` functions also operate on `bytes`, making for a perfect match:

```
with open('params.bpr', 'rb') as params_source:
    params = params_source.read()  # bytes object

params_encoded = base64.b64encode(params)
print(params_encoded.decode('ascii'))   # base64 data is always ASCII data

params_decoded = base64.b64decode(params_encoded)

with open('paramsencoded.bpr', 'wb') as new_params:
    newparams.write(params_encoded)  # write binary data

with open('paramsencoded.bpr', 'rb') as new_params:
    params_written = new_params.read()

print(params_written.decode('ascii'))  # still Base64 data, so decode as ASCII

params_decoded = base64.b64decode(params_written)  # decode the bytes value

print(params_decoded.decode('utf8'))  # assuming the original source was UTF-8
```

I explicitly use `bytes.decode(codec)` rather than `str(..., codec)` to avoid accidental `str(...)` calls.

Comment: Yes! This is it, my syntax with this type of code is awful, using `decode('ascii)` and opening the files with `wb` and `rb` treating it like bytes works well. Thanks a lot for the help!